# Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction using PDFView

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, cocoa

Good day,

I'm writing a macOS app using `PDFKit PDFView` but I'm frequently encountering the `Unexpected outstanding background CATransaction` when rapidly scrolling the `PDFView`

Most answers on SO point to updating the UI in a background thread, or updating a binding in a background thread.  However I have no bindings or any `KVC` classes.  I've removed all the `dispatch_async` calls, so that my app runs completely in the main thread, yet the crash still occurs.

Other answers say that it's a bug in the OS. If so, was it fixed or when will it be fixed (although my machine can't run the latest OS) or what is the work around in the meantime.

`lldb` shows that a thread queue called `NSScreenUpdate` was aborted due to a failed assert.

Stacktrace for this thread follows;

```
* thread #15, queue = 'NSScreenUpdate', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff52390b66 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000100abb0f0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x00007fff522ec1ae libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff3570af8e QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::assert_inactive() + 858
    frame #4: 0x00007fff28224d12 AppKit`__42-[_NSScrollingConcurrentVBLMonitor resume]_block_invoke.131 + 228
    frame #5: 0x0000000100a3bd8f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #6: 0x0000000100a503d2 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 940
    frame #7: 0x0000000100a3e48f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_source_invoke + 658
    frame #8: 0x0000000100a5014f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_continuation_pop + 297
    frame #9: 0x0000000100a4741a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 738
    frame #10: 0x0000000100a3dbea libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 723
    frame #11: 0x0000000100a3d8c3 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 116
    frame #12: 0x0000000100ab816d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1387
    frame #13: 0x0000000100ab7bed libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

I'm unable to see anything in my code that references any of these symbols.  I've also tried enabling `CATransactionDisableActions` also setting CanDrawConcurrently to NO in the `PDFView`

I've tried running `Instruments` on it but I cannot find anything unusual.

Even searching for mixtures of the significant words in the error and stack trace has been fruitless.

Hope someone can point me at the next step in resolving this.

Thank you (for reading this far)

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: What I thought was the cause mustn't be it as I haven't been able to reproduce the error in sample code.